# NullPointerException when running tests in different feature files and step definitions files

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

I did not have this issue when I had all the tests in 1 feature file and 1 step definition file. However I decided to start splitting the tests and created 2 feature files and 2 step definitions files. However, I am getting NullPointerException error.

I am using a global variables class to initialize browser and set driver, as per the below.

```
public class globalVariables {
public WebDriver driver;
public Properties prop;

public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException
{

    prop= new Properties();

    String browserName= "chrome";
    String pathToDriver = "";

    if(browserName.equals("chrome"))
    {
        pathToDriver = "C://Repositories//webDrivers//chromedriver_win32_85.83//chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathToDriver);
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //execute in chrome driver
    }
    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
}
}
```

Login Feature File (which runs first, because of opening of browser etc..)

```
 @SmokeTest
 @Login
 Feature: Queries SmokeTest
 Scenario Outline: Login using Chrome
Given I open Chrome
And I browse to Queries
When I login to Queries using "<username>" and "<password>"
And Verify that user is successfully logged in
Then Close Browser

Examples:
| username |  password |
| user1|  pass1 |
| user2|  pass2 |
```

Step definition for the Login Feature file

```
public class login_steps extends globalVariables {
@Given("I open Chrome")
public void iOpenChrome() throws Throwable {
    driver = initializeDriver();
   // throw new PendingException();
}

@When("I browse to Queries")
public void iBrowseToQueries() {
    driver.get("https://qry.com/");
   // throw new PendingException();
}

@When("I login to Queries using {string} and {string}")
public void i_login_to_queries_using_and(String string, String string2) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(string);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(string2);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
}

@Then("Verify that user is successfully logged in")
public void verifyThatUserIsSuccessfullyLoggedIn() {
    WebElement HomeButton = driver.findElement(By.id("divHomeLink"));
    Assert.assertEquals(true, HomeButton.isDisplayed());
}

@And("Close Browser")
public void closeBrowser() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Search Feature file

```
 @SmokeTest
 @Search
Feature: Queries SmokeTest
Scenario: Search Function
Given I open Chrome
And I browse to Queries
Then I login to Queries using "user1" and "pass1"
And Click on Queries Search button
And Enter keyword
And Click Search
Then Close Browser
```

Search step definition file

```
public class search_steps extends globalVariables {

@And("Click on Queries Search button")
public void clickOnQueriesSearchButton() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("imgSearchQueries")).click(); //ERROR IS HERE
}

@And("Enter keyword")
public void enterKeyword() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtKeywords")).sendKeys("Smoke Query");
}

@And("Click Search")
public void clickSearch() {
    driver.findElement(By.className("btn-search")).click();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you are using same chrome driver instance for all classes otherwise Null point exception will occur

Use global variable for driver instance

**private static Webdriver driver;**( Instatiate this on top of every classes)

Comment: It is set as public in the globalVariables class. Do I need to change that in the globalVariables class? or add that line in each step definitions file?

Comment: change that in the globalVariables clas

Comment: Or you can create one class for driver functions and use it so you will not face null point error 

if you are ok I can give that class here ?

Comment: I have wrote Util class for driver instance by using singleton pattern

Comment: I just added 'static' in my globablvariables class and it seems to be working fine. Not sure if this is good practice, but it seems to be working fine.

Comment: This is one option to ignore nullpoint exception 
If my answer working to you please accept my answer by click green tick